# Mysql return value

Tags: php, json, mysqli, auto-increment

I have a small php page like below that I would like to return the "auto-incremented_id" from this insert.

Only requirement is that I can read the number from an android application. I'm sure I could look it up but is there a code `SQL` code I can check on success that will return it?

Here's the php:

```
<?php

//Make connection
$con = mysqli_connect('xxxxx', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxx');


//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//change db to andriodnfp db
mysqli_select_db($con, 'andriodnfp');

$table = 'USER';

$fbid   = htmlspecialchars($_GET["fbid"]);
$social = htmlspecialchars($_GET["social"]);


$name = htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]);
$name = !empty($name) ? "'$name'" : "NULL";

$fname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["fname"]);
$fname = !empty($fname) ? "'$fname'" : "NULL";

$username = htmlspecialchars($_GET["username"]);
$username = !empty($username) ? "'$username'" : "NULL";

$email = htmlspecialchars($_GET["email"]);
$email = !empty($email) ? "'$email'" : "NULL";

$picture = htmlspecialchars($_GET["picture"]);
$picture = !empty($picture) ? "'$picture'" : "NULL";

$other = htmlspecialchars($_GET["other"]);
$other = !empty($other) ? "'$other'" : "NULL";

if (!$fbid == '') {

    if (!mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' ( facebookID, social_outlet, Name, first_name, username, email, picture, significant_other) VALUES ("' . $fbid . '","' . $social . '","' . $name . '","' . $fname . '","' . $username . '","' . $email . '","' . $picture . '","' . $other . '")')) {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    };
}

mysqli_close($con);

//$posts = array($json);
$posts = array(
    1
);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    'posts' => $posts
));

?>
```

Comment: Its not belongs to `android` anyway.

Comment: this is related to how to read json in Anroid application..

Comment: If the code in question is between PHP and MySQL then even if other languages are used, they are not related.

Comment: Thanks it was removed from android sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

```
if (mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ( facebookID, social_outlet, Name, first_name, username, email, picture, significant_other) VALUES ("'.$fbid.'","'.$social.'","'.$name.'","'.$fname.'","'.$username.'","'.$email.'","'.$picture.'","'.$other.'")') === false) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    die();
}
$id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

You should also probably [`die`](http://php.net/die) after an error.

Also, you should compare the query with datatype as well `===`, this ensures that it truly failed, not returned a value which evaluates to false. -- but it's not likely it returned something for an insert right?

Suppose you have a table in the database that looks like this:

```
id, username, user_level
1, dave, 0
2, jcaruso, 1
```

Suppose `user_level` was an integer, (0 = user, 1 = administrator).
Doing a select such as `SELECT user_level FROM table WHERE id=1` would return `0` and if you compare that with `==`, it would be true. `0==false`.

Comment: Thanks Alot I added the first thing i asked for, and i also set the id=0 at the start. I read up on `===` to ensure i understood what you were saying but i'm still confused. For this insert I want it to return the insert_id is all. So what would i compare it to for a type comparison?

Comment: Suppose the `INSERT` failed. You should compare it with `false`. However, if today you were using a `SELECT` statement, you could potentially select a value that returned `0` which would be equal to false. To make sure that it failed, you need to use `===`. Using `===` even in a case such as `INSERT` keeps the code in line, just in case you might want to change the statement, but still have the code working properly.

Comment: Not to be dense but can you show me the implementation i'm kinda following but i'd need to see it.

Comment: Check the edit, sorry for the confusion, this happens only on queries that return data, but it good practice nonetheless to use triple equals, just in-case you later decide to change the query.

Comment: Ok i think i understand the concept. in my situation i am returning [null] when nothing is inserted and the _id when it is inserted. Are you suggesting i turn the [null] to a 0 and then compare data types with === to ensure it is an int.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
//Make connection
$con = mysqli_connect('xxxxx','xxxxxxx','xxxxx') ;


//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//change db to andriodnfp db
mysqli_select_db($con, 'andriodnfp');

$table= 'USER';

$fbid = htmlspecialchars($_GET["fbid"]);
$social = htmlspecialchars($_GET["social"]);


$name = htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]);
$name = !empty($name) ? "'$name'" : "NULL";

$fname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["fname"]);
$fname = !empty($fname) ? "'$fname'" : "NULL";

$username = htmlspecialchars($_GET["username"]);
$username = !empty($username) ? "'$username'" : "NULL";

$email = htmlspecialchars($_GET["email"]);
$email = !empty($email) ? "'$email'" : "NULL";

$picture = htmlspecialchars($_GET["picture"]);
$picture = !empty($picture) ? "'$picture'" : "NULL";

$other = htmlspecialchars($_GET["other"]);
$other = !empty($other) ? "'$other'" : "NULL";

//$posts = array($json);
$posts = array(1);

if (!$fbid == '') {

    if (!mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ( facebookID, social_outlet, Name, first_name, username, email, picture, significant_other) VALUES ("'.$fbid.'","'.$social.'","'.$name.'","'.$fname.'","'.$username.'","'.$email.'","'.$picture.'","'.$other.'")')) {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    };

    $auto_id = 'autoincramented_id';

    //passyour primary key here
    $cql  = "SELECT MAX($auto_id) AS primary_id FROM {$table}";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $cql);

    $id_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    //$posts = array($json);
    $posts = array('auto_increment_id'=>$id_result['primary_id']);


}

mysqli_close($con);


header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));

?>
```